# How do I eliminate all these if-else

Tags: javascript, filter, graphql

I have written this code to filter a "books" array, depending on the author or genre have been given as a parameter:-

```
//This code works perfectly fine as is
allBooks: (root, args) => {
      if (args.author === undefined && args.genre === undefined) {
        return books
      } else if (args.author === undefined) {
        return books.filter((book) => book.genres.includes(args.genre))
      } else if (args.genre === undefined) {
        return books.filter((book) => book.author === args.author)
      } else {
        const booksFilter = books.filter((book) => book.author === args.author)
        return booksFilter.filter((book) => book.genres.includes(args.genre))
      }
    }
```

I believe there must be some way to write this more "professionally" without using all these if-else. So if anyone knows a better way, I'll appreciate it.

[Edited]
Thanks to all, I decided to go with ghostkraviz solution, code looks like this now:

```
allBooks: (root, args) => {
      return books.filter((book) => {
        const filteredGenres = book.genres.filter((genre) =>
          genre.includes(args.genre || "")
       );
       return book.author.includes(args.author || "") && filteredGenres.length > 0;
      })
    }
```

Comment: You can use switch. https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/switch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since String.prototype.includes actually checks if a string maybe found within another string (the parameter) [MDN String.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes). that means, for undefined args you could default it to empty string. Empty strings will return true if checked with .includes from any string.

you only check for 2 args which are the author & genre.
here's the example:

```js
const books = [
  {author: "A", genres: ["Horror", "romance"]},
  {author: "B", genres: ["romance"]},
  {author: "X", genres: ["science"]},
  {author: "C", genres: ["science", "Horror"]}
];

const allBooks = (root, args) => {
      return books.filter(book => {
        const filteredGenres = book.genres.filter(genre =>
          genre.includes(args.genre || "")
       );
       return book.author.includes(args.author || "") && filteredGenres.length > 0;
  });
};

    console.log('filtered Horror = ', allBooks({}, {genre: 'Horror'}));
    console.log('filtered A and Horror = ', allBooks({}, {author: 'A', genre: 'Horror'}));
    console.log('filtered romance = ', allBooks({}, {genre: 'romance'}));
// for all books result
console.log('filtered romance = ', allBooks({}, {}));
 // for an author result
console.log('filtered author(A) = ', allBooks({}, {author:"A"}));
```

Comment: In the question, books have multiple genres rather than just one.

Comment: oh damn, yes fill fix this

Comment: Hi, this works partially, if I filter with only author it returns an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

You could take an array for filtering with key/value pairs, like

```
filters = [
    ['author', 'eliot'],
    ['genre', 'fiction']
]
```

and an object for storing special type of searching, like

```
methods = {
    genre: 'includes'
}
```

Together, you get the following function

```
result = books.filter(book => filter.every(([key, value]) => key in methods
    ? book[key][methods[key]](value)
    : book[key] === value
));
```

Because of [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)'s return value of `true` for empty arrays, you need no further action to get all books.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the version below is written more "professionally" as it looks messy, but it is a single line, and does not use if-else.

```
books = [{
    author: "a", 
    genres: ["a"]},
{author: "a", 
    genres: ["a", "b"]},
{author: "b", 
    genres: ["c", "b"]
}];
allBooks = (root, args) => {
      return (!args.author && !args.genre) ? books : (!args.author) ? 
      books.filter((book) => book.genres.includes(args.genre)):(!args.genre)? 
      books.filter((book) => book.author === args.author) : 
      (books.filter((book) => book.author === args.author)).filter((book) => 
      book.genres.includes(args.genre));
}

console.log(allBooks("",{genre: "b"})); 
//console:
//0: {author: "a", genres: Array(2)}
//1: {author: "b", genres: Array(2)}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use if-else, as it's more readable. We can also eliminate the else-ifs since each of the if statement has a return.

This is just a simplified version of your existing codes without the else-ifs and curly brackets

```
allBooks: (root, args) => {
      const { author, genre } = args;
      if (!author && !genre) return books;
      if (!author) return books.filter((book) => book.genres.includes(genre))
      if (!genre) return books.filter((book) => book.author === author);

      return books.filter((book) => book.author === author).filter((book) => book.genres.includes(genre))
      
}
```

**Sometimes it's not about writing codes professionally.**

**It's about writing codes that you can easily understand.**